# Implementing an ADC Interface to connect to a FPGA

Tags: fpga, adc, vhdl, intel-fpga, texas-instruments

I want to implement an ADC Interface for an ADC - ADS 7230 (TI) in VHDL. 
I am not very familiar with ADCs to implement it in VHDL. I already have 
an ADC Interface for a 10 bit ADC (MAX 1030) and a 12-bit ADC (LTC1407). 
Unfortunately these are in AHDL.

Is it possible to use any of the existing ADC interfaces and adapt it to 
suit ADS 7230 in AHDL itself? If yes, what are the necessary details I 
should look into from the data sheet to change the existing ADC 
interface available in AHDL?

Or do you have any other suggestions to implement an ADC interface in 
the quickest possible way?

Is there any link where I can get a reference of a 12-bit ADC in VHDL 
similar to ADS 7230?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Micro-Nova Mercury card has a Spartan3 and an external ADC.  They provide the VHDL driver here:  http://www.micro-nova.com/s/MercuryADC_139.zip

It's a simple SPI protocol, similar to the one used by [ADS7230](http://www.ti.com/product/ads7230).

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I am not clear whether to use the SCLK(50Mhz) for conversion for which I need a counter upto 42 clks (including CFR write/read) or use  a CCLK which counts upto 18 clks. Which would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Altera MAX 10, it has an on-chip 12-bit ADC. Cheap development boards are available and VHDL and Verilog may be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still relatively new to FPGA but I went through this process recently. It's all about the comm protocol rather than the adc itself. The Max1030 uses the exact same interface so the module should hook straight up.

The hardware you already have will have two separate components; the data handling and the communication protocol container. As the protocol is the same you should be able to adjust the data to fit the new ADC.

I recently built an I2C interface for an ADS1114. It took 3 weeks but then only half a day to adjust it for use in a CMOS image sensor. So it's well worth going through the process.

Also it doesn't matter what HDL you use as they all get mapped to the same technology but you need to understand the technology and the component or structure that the HDL represents.

Hope I've convinced you to get stuck into it.

Hayden